# on change in boolean

Tags: python, odoo

I want asked

I have 2 boolean (checkbox) so I want make like this.

when I click first boolean (checkbox), boolean second is true but if I click second boolean, condition first checkbox is false.

how I can make like that ? thank you

Comment: This not enough information. Do you want both bool1 and bool2 to be True when you click bool1 and Flase when you click bool2? Or do you want e.g. bool1 to stay  on click in its state but change the others'?

Comment: @MaxPowers no..bool1 True but when bool2 True, the bool1 became False

Comment: does it means that if i click bool1 = True bool2 will be True and if i click bool2 True bool will be True ?? or or Something else

Comment: @firebug if I click bool1 = true, bool2 will be false, but if bool2 = true, bool1 will be false

Comment: ah got it check below piece of code

Comment: @firebug ok. it seem like that. I call in xml file `on_change="on_change_bool1()"` but the error like this  **on_change_bool1() takes exactly 5 arguments (4 given)** please help me again

Comment: @JC you shoue write your xml on change like  `on_change="on_change_bool1(bool1)` and `on_change="on_change_bool2(bool2)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can write on change method where you can return the value of the other field or same field . So your code may look like this, on first field on change method :

```
def on_change_bool1(self, cr, uid, ids, bool1):
    return {'value':{'bool1':bool1,'bool2':False}}
```

Code on Second field on change function

```
def on_change_bool2(self, cr, uid, ids, bool2):
    return {'value':{'bool2': bool2,'bool1':False}}
```

Yes here you can change business logic but keep in mind that on change it can return cause of multiple field and that value will be set so if you want to set some Boolean field false by force return false by force so you can never ever able to make it true. Or you can choose you Business logic same way.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: NO...NO..thank you so much @firebug. if can I want kiss u haha..joke..thank you so much my friend. your the best....

Comment: sorry may I asked a little again. how I bool1 is true but if u click in bool1, it will be false, but I don't want like that. I want if bool1 true and i click it again, bool1 still true

Comment: play condition checking with the value you are getting on param and return value according for the fields results.